# Make Image have Brushed metal look

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

Picture 1

[image]

picture 2

[image]

Can someone tell me how the developer made picture 1 into picture 2 in Photoshop or illustrator?

Comment: It will not be possible to give steps to achieve what someone else has done. In photoshop there are more than one way to do any effect. I suggest you look up on tutorials for brushed metal effect and then make changes to that till you get desired results. Or if you should contact the designer.

Comment: Hi Brutiquzz, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use grunge maps as overlays for your base image in Photoshop. grunge maps are just images which are usually black and white that are used for adding small dirt-like details to images. you can find pictures of scratches and concrete to use as gunge maps from a site like [cgtextures](http://www.cgtextures.com) since the images on this site are free for any use.

Here's the process:

1. I downloaded these textures from cgtextures

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

2. I opened your original picture in Photoshop and added the downloaded images as layers and desaturated them by going to image->adjustments->desaturate which makes them black and white.

[image: Images as layers]

3. Change the blending mode of all the grunge map layers from normal to multiply.

[image: Multiply]

4. You should get an image that's quite dark so you must use the levels adjustment or the brightness and contrast adjustment to lighten the grunge maps.

Go to image->adjustments->levels and adjust for each grunge map.

[image: Levels]

5.(Optional) Use the gradient tool to make a black and white circle layer on top of everything and set the layer blending mode to multiply then adjust the brightness and contrast.

[image: All the layers used]

6. This is the final result using the low resolution base image provided in the question.

[image: Result]

As others said, there's more than one way to achieve this effect so I don't think this is a suitable question as some methods will not always work.

Comment: Hi Polar1ty, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Great answer, though I think one of the grunge layers would need to be inverted and set to something like screen (probably with a mask of its own) to achieve some of those light scratches in picture 2.

Comment: @KJP That is correct. I didn't take note of the lighter scratches.

Comment: thank you so much. Now i get the idea on how to approach this!